# Passwords in the clear in logs

Tags: hash, passwords, bcrypt

I am aware that there are a number of reasons why passwords CAN end up in logs in the clear - for instance, I see this mentioned in the context of debug logs with some frequency - but I was wondering if someone could explain the mechanics of how this works assuming a web application hashes passwords that are submitted by a user and compares the hash to the one stored by the site operator.

For instance, let's say a user goes to a website, enters a username and password, and clicks submit. I would have assumed that the password is immediately hashed (let's say with bcrypt) and compared to the hash associated with the entered username in a database. How, then, would the plaintext password end up in a log? Does the entered password somehow get logged before the hashing takes place? And if so, is that a security failure?

Comment: If passwords appear in the logs, somebody made a horrible error in implementing their security. There is *no* good reason for passwords, in the clear or in a form that can be decrypted, to appear in logs. If there is any way for somebody to obtain a password by examining logs, then it's a security failure.

Comment: @JimMischel So you are saying the query string should not be in the logs.

Answer (score 4):

Passwords are usually hashed server side, not on the client. If the password would be sent in a GET request it would end up plain text in the log.

To prevent the password to end up in a log file, one should use a POST request.

To protect the password from a man-in-the-middle attack, it should be passed only over an encrypted HTTPS/SSL connection. Client side hashing would not protect the password, because a man-in-the-middle could simply strip away the script which does the hashing.

Comment: @zaph - Well that's exactly what I wrote in the last phrase. But thanks anyway, just changed the priority of the phrases.

Comment: The re-ordering does help.

Comment: I think client-side hashing with HTTPS/SSL would protect the password more effectively than server-side hashing while preventing a man-in-the-middle (MITM) attack equally effectively.  In this case it is more effective protection for the password because the plaintext password never leaves the client, so the server never has it and never has to protect it.  HTTPS/SSL protects data in both directions, preventing the attacker from stripping away the script that does the hashing.

Comment: @Slartibartfast - The only thing the server must do with the password is hashing. But your are right, there is a small benefit in client-and-server-side hashing, maybe you want to have a look at another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50714929/575765) about exactly this topic.

Comment: In the context of this question, the client-side hashing completely protects against user passwords showing up in the clear in the logs (doesn't matter if you GET or POST, or write the cleartext transaction to disk on the server).  The answer you link to is not relevant to this questions explicit goals.

Comment: @Slartibartfast - One should not neglect best practices, to get a side effect. The POST request will solve the problem with the log as well, without fiddling with the password storage. Client side hashing on the other side, will change the way we store passwords and we have to know exactly what we are doing, the pros, the cons and the whys. Hashing only on the client-side, would e.g. solve the log problem, but would decrease security, which cannot be our goal. That's why I linked the answer, to show that there is indeed a small benefit in client-side hashing, but it should be well-considered.